# Prevent [.data.frame drop dimensions where there is only one column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `demos`, with `n` columns (depends on external input), where `n = 1,2,3 ...`

I want to delete certain rows, then add new columns to this data frame. When `n > 1`, the following code works fine, where `demos.part` is always an R `data.frame`.

```
demos.part <- demos[-i, ]  // remove i-th row
demos.part[,"new column name"] <- as.vector(<new data>)
```

However when `n == 1`, the `demos.part` in the first line becomes an `vector`. Then the second line does not work anymore.

Of course we can hard code to fix the special case. Is there a consistent (elegant) way to remove rows from `data.frame` and still return a `data.frame`, even if the data frame has only one column?

Comment: maybe use `as.data.frame` ?

Comment: @rbm `as.data.frame` feels like ad-hoc solution. when `n>1`, `as.data.frame(demos[-i,])` is kind of redundant. When `n==1`, `as.data.frame(demos[-i,])` changes the column name in original `demos`. Then I have to do `colnames<-` again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first line, `demos.part <- demos[-i, ]`, would only drop from a data frame to a matrix if `demis.part` has exactly one column:

```
# One column: result is a vector
> data.frame(a=letters)[1,]
[1] a
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
# 2 cols: result is a df with 1 row
> data.frame(a=letters, b=letters)[1,]
data.frame with 1 row and 2 columns
         a        b
  <factor> <factor>
1        a        a
```

To see why this is, you can inspect the arguments of `[.data.frame`, where the default value of the `drop` argument depends on the number of columns:

```
> args(`[.data.frame`)
function (x, i, j, drop = if (missing(i)) TRUE else length(cols) == 
    1) 
NULL
```

Regardless, any time you want to prevent dropping of dimensions, simply add `drop=FALSE` after any indexing arguments (including intentionally blank indexing arguments; note the empty space between the two commas for the blank column index):

```
> data.frame(a=letters)[1, , drop=FALSE]
data.frame with 1 row and 1 column
         a
  <factor>
1        a
```

You should always use `drop=FALSE` when deciding how many rows/columns to select based on external input, since there is always the possibility that it will select just one row. Alternatively, use the `data_frame` function from the dplyr package to create a data frame with fewer weird edge cases in its behavior:

```
> library(dplyr)
> data_frame(a=letters)[1,]
Source: local data frame [1 x 1]

      a
  (chr)
1     a
```

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your command about the `colnames` - i don't think they disappear. 
Consider following code:

```
remove.row <- function(df,n) { as.data.frame(df[-n,]) }
#
a <- data.frame(col1=c(1,2),col2=c("A","B"))
a
class(a)
colnames(a)
#
a <- remove.row(a,1)
a
class(a)
colnames(a)
#
a <- remove.row(a,1)
a
class(a)
colnames(a)
```

produces:

```
> a
  col1 col2
1    1    A
2    2    B
> class(a)
[1] "data.frame"
> colnames(a)
[1] "col1" "col2"
> #
> a <- remove.row(a,1)
> a
  col1 col2
2    2    B
> class(a)
[1] "data.frame"
> colnames(a)
[1] "col1" "col2"
> #
> a <- remove.row(a,1)
> a
[1] col1 col2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> class(a)
[1] "data.frame"
> colnames(a)
[1] "col1" "col2"
```

Comment: please try the case when there is only one column in the `data.frame`

Comment: oh ok, i see what you mean, but in this case i'd simply handle it as a corner case in the helper function.